# Can filter by file upload description but not sort by it?

Tags: views

I have a simple page/content type where a user can upload files and give them a description.

I then hide that field on the page and display the files using a view in a block.

I can get it to show the files no problem and display them with a custom output, however I just can't seem to be able to sort by the text description, rather than the filename - the field just isn't there to sort by.

The description field does however show up in Filter Criteria where I've exposed it to allow users to search for files using the file description rather than the file name.

I'm not really sure how/where to look as I've tried all sorts of combos of the fields I have and none of them seem to be what I need.

Any help appreciated!

[image: quick pic of my view setup]

Answer (score 0):

to sort by a field you should have that field in the result of view, in your example you can sort by the field "Resource Upload" because it figure in FIELDS section.. so to sort by "Description" field you have to add it first to FIELDS section and you can hide it later.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, however the description field is not available for the fields section. From what I understand of everything I've read, the description "field" for the file upload is not an actual field, but stored as part of the file upload field somehow.

Comment: That's not true. You don't have to have a field in results to sort by it. What you do need is to have an entry for it in the views data defined by whatever modules are installed.